# Memcached на сервере

Tags: php, memcached, memcache

Здравствуйте! Установил и настроил на debian memcached, так же настроил сайт для работы. Но показывает вместо русского текста такое:
����� ���������������� ������� ����� ��

В чём дело? Кодировка utf-8.

Comment: Что именно показывает "такое"?

Comment: На сайте показывает вместо русского текста.

Comment: Та-ак. И на чём он сделан, как общается с memcached?

Comment: Добавил к вопросу код.

Comment: И вы уверены, что проблема возникла именно после внедрения memcached, что её не существовало когда memcached не было?

Comment: Сайт работает на utf-8 без memcached и всё норм. Подключаю memcached и вместо текста такое